# Copy constructor and function returning temporaries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, copy-constructor

I have the following piece of code:

```
    struct balls
    {
        int mNumBalls;

        ~balls();    
    };

    inline balls::~balls()
    {
          // is not called in VS2010 when getBalls returns in monkey constructor
    }

    balls getBalls()
    {
        balls myBalls;

        myBalls.mNumBalls = 5;

        return myBalls;
    }

    struct monkey
    {
        balls mBalls;

        monkey();
    };

    inline monkey::monkey() : mBalls(getBalls())
    {
    }
```

By stepping in the VS2010 debugger, I notice the `balls` destructor is not called when `getBalls()` returns in the `monkey()` constructor. Is this defined in the c++ standard or merely some optimization that only exists on VC++? Can I rely on the destructor not being called in this case cross-platform?

Thanks

Comment: `getBalls() { balls myBalls; return myBalls; }` `monkey { balls mBalls; }`  ... lol

Comment: I was happy with the original version. Any code which reads `monkey balls` brings a smile to my face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Paragraph 12.8/31 of the C++11 Standard:

> When certain criteria are met, **an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
>   object**, *even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object
>   have side effects*. In such cases, the implementation treats the source and target of the omitted copy/move
>   operation as simply two different ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of that object
>   occurs at the later of the times when the two objects would have been destroyed without the optimization. **This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances** (which
>   may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> — **in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a
>   non-volatile automatic object** (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) **with the same cvunqualified
>   type as the function return type**, the copy/move operation can be omitted by **constructing
>   the automatic object directly into the function’s return value**
>
> — [...]

This is one of those cases:

```
balls getBalls()
{
    balls myBalls;

    return myBalls; <== COVERED BY THE QUOTED PARAGRAPH
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

and it is a really relevant one, in that it represents an *exception* to the general "*as if*" rule. The "*as if*" rule basically allows compilers to change the code you wrote *as long as the effect is the same* ("*as if*" it executed exactly the program you wrote).

In this case, however, you cannot rely on the compiler creating a temporary (or *not* creating a temporary!), even though your copy constructor, move constructor, or destructor have side effects.

Answer (score 2):

You're meeting *copy elision*, which is a well-defined mechanism. It is up to the implementation to not perform unnecessary copies.

Comment: Is there any major compiler which does not do this? Can I safely rely on the destructor not being called across the major platforms (say windows, osx, linux, android, ps3)

Comment: @KaiserJohaan: No, you cannot *rely* on this. It's a compiler's choice. Practically, all compiler will do this in most situations. However, you must not assume anything about it. This is an exception to the "as if" rule.

Comment: @KaiserJohaan: It's not that "the destructor is never called". You just have one less copy than you expected. There will still be a destructor call when the `monkey` object is destroyed.

Comment: On a more practical note: These optimizations, often called Return Value Optimization (RVO) and Named Return Value Optimization (NRVO) are implemented in all major compilers, in case of VC++ and GCC, they were added about 10 *years* ago! My experience is that they work very reliable *if your code allows them*. My advice is thus: Write correct code which allows the copies to be remove and you can be reasonably sure that the temporaries are removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return a complex structure by value, the only guaranteed way to avoid unnecessary construction and destruction is to use move semantics. See [How to: Write a Move Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665.aspx).

For example, if your class allocates memory, the move constructor allows you to transfer ownership of the memory from one variable to another. The optimiser will then remove the redundant stores and null checks of the transferred variable.